# How to step through decompiled 3rd party code in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, decompiler

I would like to step through 3rd party code while debugging my application in Eclipse. I've tried both jadclipse and jd-eclipse. In both cases, the decompiled code is shown when I, eg, click on a class in a stack trace in the console. However, if I try to "step into" the 3rd party code, I always get "source not found". Is there anything that will let me step through the decompiled source while debugging my app? I'm using Helios.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the decompiled source folder to the jar in the project settings? In the project properties can you go to "Java Build Path", select the libraries tab, each jar will be an expandable tree. Expand the tree, and there is a "Source Attachment Option" try adding the decompiled source folder here.